# OpenSSL “error: storage size of ‘ctx’ isn’t known”

Tags: c, openssl

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and (supposedly) OpenSSL 1.1.1b, however whilst using `EVP_MD_CTX` I am getting this issue when compiling code that should otherwise work. I toyed around with OpenSSL (trying to update manually on 18.04) however did uninstall/reinstall successfully (to my knowledge) as it now displays the version mentioned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
const EVP_MD *md;
char mess1[] = "Test Message\n";
char mess2[] = "Hello World\n";
unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
int md_len, i;

OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

md = EVP_get_digestbyname(argv[1]);

EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, md, NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, mess2, strlen(mess2));
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);

printf("Digest is: ");
for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++) printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
printf("\n");
}
```

I understand similar questions to this have been asked, however upon attempting the fixes stated as answers I've not been able to remedy mine.

The exact error is:

```
test2.c:6:12: error: storage size of ‘mdctx’ isn’t known
 EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with OpenSSL 1.1, the `EVP_MD_CTX` type is an opaque type so you can't create an instance of it.

You need to instead call `EVP_MD_CTX_create()` which returns a `EVP_MD_CTX *` you can use in calls to other functions.  When you're done using it, call `EVP_MD_CTX_destroy` to clean up he resources.

```
EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;

mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess2, strlen(mess2));
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
```

Comment: That got rid of a lot of errors! The ones left I'm also a bit unsure of how to fix: 


`test2.c:32:37: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘EVP_DigestFinal_ex’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
 EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);`



`In file included from test2.c:2:
/usr/local/include/openssl/evp.h:548:12: note: expected ‘unsigned int *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 __owur int EVP_DigestFinal_ex(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *md,` 


Are these straightforward to fix, or does this warrant a new question entirely? Thank you once again!

Comment: @JosephSmith use unsigned ints for the values

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I should have spotted that myself...doh. Thank you haha.

Comment: @JosephSmith in general with all sorts of crypto you want to use unsigneds all the time.